# How to use lagged features in regression (Python)

Tags: python, regression

If I am trying to use regression to predict out different time horizons (for example, predict out 1 year from now, 3 years, 5 years, etc.), how can I use lagged variables in my model? For example, I have 5 years of historical data -- if I am predicting one year into the future, can I only use the previous year's data? If I am predicting 3 years out, can I only use my historical data going back three years?

Comment: Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches.